# javascript onclick apostrophe quotation mark issue

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

Ok, I'm getting some data from an ajax call and need to store the value as a parameter to an onclick element via javascript.

Eg

```
output = "<a href = '#' onclick = 'deleteFileName('" + trim(splitString[i]) + "')'> delete File </a>";
```

This behaves strangely. When I inspect the element with chrome, the output looks like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="deleteFileName("0design mockup.xlsx')'> delete File </a>
```

It should obviously look like this

```
<a href = "#" onclick = "deleteFileName('0design mockup.xlsx')">
```

The parameter is a String so I need the quotes around it. This may not be the best way to do this, but why is it making the first two quotes double quotes and then the last two single quotes?

*This is a JSP server using ajax calls to gather information. The function "deleteFileName(fileNameIn)" is an ajax call. (I don't believe this is necessary information but you never know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the same kinds of quotes for the value of onclick and for the function call. You need single quotes for one and double quotes for the other (where to put which should not matter). Otherwise you are closing the onclick attribute with the first single quote of the function call.

Example:

```
output = "<a href = '#' onclick = 'deleteFileName(\"" + trim(splitString[i]) + "\")'> delete File </a>";
```

Comment: gah, ok that was just silly of me. I see now, in my little world I had decided that single quotes were treated differently than double quotes lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inspecting the information, I suggest that you wget or curl the page directly (or use the browser's view-source function).  These days I've found that many browsers present information subtly incorrectly in the inspector in their attempt to format everything nicely.

Removing the browser from the equation is a good first step, since that will show you exactly where the problem is occuring.

Comment: Viewing the source doesn't help since I use javascript to paste database information after the page has been loaded. The source info is just the basic HTML I laid out (divs/tables) and used Javascript to populate after the fact since the information is very dynamic. My IDE has no diagnostic features and I'm on a company machine that won't allow me to download new software :(